# Is there only one analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

If I were to manipulate the zeta function in a 'new way' would I end up with an analytic continuation that is equal to the one know or something completely new for values less than 1 and complex numbers?

Comment: If you want a great text to begin your CA endeavors, I was in a similar situation and found this text by Flanigan http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486613887 an excellent choice.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the advice, I am glad to hear I am not alone in my interest!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analytic continuations to a specified domain are always unique (due to the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) for holomorphic functions).

Comment: Due to my mathematics knowledge so far (I am still learning), I have no idea what you just wrote, but I will look into it!

Comment: Roughly: Two analytic functions that are equal on an open set are equal everywhere, so if you have two different continuations of $\zeta$ that agree on $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, they agree everywhere.

Comment: @zerosofthezeta There's something that I can't understand, you are asking about a new way to manipulate the zeta Riemann function with     some different analytic continuation and you still don't know the identity principle. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @GastónBurrull I am new to this field, but I have an immense interest!

Comment: @zerosofthezeta If you haven't done so already, you really should start with a course in complex analysis.

Comment: @mrf Yes. I am going to very soon. Thanks for the advice.